# Connect to Oracle Database from Azure Function App

Tags: c#, oracle, azure, azure-functions

I have a Function App that needs to connect to an Oracle DB. The .csproj file looks similar to this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core" Version="3.21.80" />
    
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and the functions looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace TestOracleConn
{
    public class TestOracleConn
    {
        [FunctionName("TestOracleConn")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */3 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"1. C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

            try
            {
                // Connect to Oracle
                string constr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =" +
                                "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = myHost)(PORT = ****))" +
                                "(CONNECT_DATA =" +
                                "(SERVICE_NAME=myServiceName.oraclecloud.com)));" +
                                "User Id=myUser;Password=*****";                
                
                log.LogInformation($"2. before initializing the Oracle connection class");

                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
                log.LogInformation($"3. After initializing Oracle connection BUT before open()");
                con.Open();
 
                // Display Version Number
                log.LogInformation("4. Connected to Oracle " + con.ServerVersion); 
 
                // Close and Dispose OracleConnection
                con.Close();
                con.Dispose();
                
                log.LogInformation($"5. after close");   
            }
            catch (Exception excp)
            {
                log.LogInformation("TestOracleConn Something went wrong " + excp.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have not downloaded any library to my local system or in Azure portal.
I have no tnsname.ora file or any similar file.

When I try to connect to the oracle DB, i.e. when this function runs in the portal, I get this error:

```
TestOracleConn Something went wrong ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file
```

I have searched in the internet, but didn't find a solution to this error or any example for how to connect to Oracle DB in Azure function.

Is there anyone that has any suggestion for this problem?

PS: I have also tried to used an unmanaged DB Connection class, like `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` from this nuget package: `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core Version=3.21.80`. But, it give me also a similar error (i.e. `System.IO.FileLoadException`)

PS2: I can't test to run this function locally in my machine because of some security configurations and permission

Comment: Hi - did you ever find out your issue with this?  I am trying to do the same thing with a connection string the same as yours to on-prem.  I get a connection timeout so slightly different to your error but I see no traffic coming through the firewall from my virtual desktop.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I have unfortuantly left the project but, I myself haven't find a solution, but I am sure that my colleage had solved the issue but maybe he used a different library or different code design. I can't remember the details now

Answer (score 0):

In an Azure function I solved that problem. This is my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.OracleClient" Version="1.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="oci.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="orannzsbb11.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="oraocci11.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="oraociei11.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="oraociicus11.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I copied those libraries to the root of the project and to the bin/release and bin/debug folders. At the solution explorer, right click on each .dll, properties, copy to output directory, copy always.